# SQL Server Management Font Colour (color) Issue

Tags: sql-server

I just installed **Microsoft SQL Server Management 2012** and everything works fine 
except I get a very strange font and backcolor issue which I have no idea why it's happening.

I have not modified any of the colors so I am very bewildered by it.

Any one have any idea what is causing this:

[image: Dark blue background with Black Font]

Comment: go to tools -> options -> environment -> fonts and colors and click the use defaults button on the top right corner.

Comment: I already tried resetting to default but it doesn't go away :( - Seems to happen on any `numbers` I type

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Restarted the system it and it seems to have worked now... Thanks!

Comment: When all else fails, restart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your background setting in Tools --> Options

[image]

Comment: Why would that affect a region of exactly 5 characters and not the rest of the text?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Good question - No idea how it happened something to do with numbers I think